# Include All Stories in VBA RegEx Search in MS Word

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm looking for a solution to be able to perform RegEx searches in MS Word. I've been using the following code to achieve this (it highlights matching strings; I can then search for instances of highlighting using Word's built-in search function), but it is limited to the main document only. For my purposes, it is crucial I be able to include any other stories -- most especially any endnotes and/or footnotes -- in my searches.

Does anyone have a solution for including the endnote and footnote stories in a search of this kind?

```
Sub RegexHighlight()

Set RegExp = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
With RegExp
.Global = True
.Pattern = InputBox("Find what:")
For Each Match In RegExp.Execute(ActiveDocument.Range.Text)
    ActiveDocument.Range(Match.FirstIndex, Match.FirstIndex + Match.Length) _
    .HighlightColorIndex = wdYellow
Next
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Why not just loop through `ActiveDocument.StoryRanges`? I'm not sure how that would work with RegEx as I prefer to use Word's built-in search function with wildcards, but if you need to use RegEx it's somewhere for you to start.

Comment: https://wordmvp.com/FAQs/Customization/ReplaceAnywhere.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example which searches all stories

```
Sub RegexHighlight()

Dim Match As Object
Dim Pattern As String
Dim Story As Range

Pattern = InputBox("Find what:")
If Pattern = "" Then Exit Sub

With CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    .Global = True
    .Pattern = Pattern
    For Each Story In ActiveDocument.storyRanges
        Do While Not Story Is Nothing
            For Each Match In .Execute(Story)
                Story.SetRange Match.FirstIndex, Match.FirstIndex + Match.Length
                Story.HighlightColorIndex = wdYellow
            Next
            Set Story = Story.NextStoryRange
        Loop
    Next
End With
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I was looking to be able to do. I appreciate your help.